# Does Google follow and count a backlink that goes through a JavaScript location.href redirect page?

Tags: googlebot, google-index, backlinks

example.com has a link on their website which is on same domain like,

```
<a href="https://example.com?ref=mywebsite.tld">Reference</a>
```

`example.com?ref=mywebsite.tld` doesn't redirect with 302/301, it's just opening a blank page with a few line of javascript code and redirect to our website with javascript on page load,

```
location.href = "http://mywebsite.tld"
```

Does Google count this type of redirection as backlink?

Answer (score 3):

Actually, only 301 redirection pass the Page Authority (PA) to target page and javascript redirection does not pass the PA, so you can not count on this type of redirection as a backlink.